# How to set slanted edge for image or video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put slanted edge for inlined images/video side by side such as this website - http://campaign.mcdonalds.com.tw/McCafe/ does

[image: this part of the website]

How can I achieve this slanted edge effect?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your layout is organized, but generally you can achieve this effect by using the transform css property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Especially skew or skewY will help you here.
Something like this.

```
transform: skewY(-15deg);
```